# Хранение названий фотографий товара в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Допустим есть некий товар, к этому товару можно добавть N'ное количество фотографий.

Сабж, как на ваше мнение лучше хранить названия фотографий в одном поле таблицы БД.

Пока есть два варианта:

1-й сериализация

```
a:5:{i:0;s:5:"1.jpg";i:1;s:5:"2.jpg";i:2;s:5:"3.jpg";i:3;s:5:"4.jpg";i:4;s:5:"5.jpg";}
```

2-й разделители

```
1.jpg|2.jpg|3.jpg|4.jpg|5.jpg
```

Я конечно склоняюсь 1-му варианту, минимум извращений при записи в БД `serialize($_POST['file'])`

Голосуем)

Может у кого еще есть какие идеи по этому поводу?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

создание отдельной таблицы как  раз оптимальное решение.

- Во первых, на размере данных это сильно не скажется.
- Во вторых, нет ограничения на кол-во картинок к одной записи.
- В третьих, легко удалять определенную картинку.
- Можно легко расширить таблицу, к примеру, завтра понадобиться сделать подписи к картинкам или "лайки".

И ещё много плюсов.

Comment: Не хотел конечно делать для этого отдельную таблицу, но после этого "уже ответа", не могу несклониться к отдельной таблице)

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте первую нормальную форму БД. Если в поле нужно внести несколько значений, значит их нужно выносить в отдельную таблицу. К предложенным вами вариантам могу добавить третий  - JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Табдица с полями `id_tovara` и `name_fotografiy`.

Нет отношения 1 к многим)

Comment: Причем тут имена полей? вопрос конкретно о структуре хранимых данных!

--

Или вы предлагаете для каждого фото создавать отдельное поле в отдельной таблице? Не лучший вариант!